# What is the way to mock rest service response without changing code

Tags: rest, mocking

I am working on one java/scala based service which uses some internal scala libraries
that make rest calls (at least to 5 differnt endpoints , these provide some reference data) to multiple other services in order to support main service

When I am running the main service in one of these environments and one of the supproting
service is down the work is blocked, the scala library does not support passing of the url
as a -D system property , so if one of the service is down there is no option
to select url for just that service in some other environment.

only option is to switch the environmnet which poses some other challanges in terms of 
the transactional data.

we dont want to change the library locally to hardcode the url variables and use them locally
because it takes time to change poms etc.
Changing values at debug time is also possible as these urls are vals in scala and we can not
change the value at debugging time.

So Is there way to around this or any kind of tool that will return a dummy response by intercepting
the rest url locally.

e.g. if i call http://qa.company.com/masterdata1 it should return json { "id":"dummy","value":"value" ....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there are no answers so far...

I'll suggest getting the API Simulator or similar tool that supports being called as HTTP/S proxy; building it yourself can also be an option, of course. (disclaimer: I'm involved with API Simulator)

You would have to configure the java/scala-based service that calls those other services you want to mock to use API Simulator as HTTP/S proxy. See the [doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) on setting `-Dhttps.proxyHost` and `-Dhttps.proxyPort` for HTTPS calls, and `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` for HTTP, respectively; `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts` is for excluding hosts from being proxied.

The simulator will get/intercept those calls and if there is simlet defined to match a given request, the simlet will return the configured simulated response - static mock/stub, or template-based and dynamically generated. Unmatched requests can be forwarded automatically to the actual live services or a pre-configured default response can be returned.

The above assumes that the java/scala-based service supports using HTTP/S proxy. This way, without changing the actual URLs or any code, you can mock some service responses and get live responses for others.